# Import dashboard in Apache Superset through REST API

Tags: apache-superset

I'm trying to import the Superset dashboard through API but currently not successful yet.
I'm following Superset API docs to import with endpoint:

```
/api/v1/dashboard/import
```

My import payload as below:

```
POST /api/v1/dashboard/import/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8088
Authorization: Bearer <access token>
Content-Length: 289
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="formData"; filename="20210615_065115.json"
Content-Type: application/json

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="overwrite"

True
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

I got a response with status `200` but the dashboard was not imported, and in the preview response on Postman I got this output:
[image]

Anybody can help with this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Superset documentation isn't very clear about this but I finally managed to solve this problem.

As you can see your response is redirecting you to a login page.
What you need to do is to first make a `GET` request to `/api/v1/security/csrf_token/`

And add header in your request to `/api/v1/dashboard/import`

`'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token`

Another incorrect thing in the documentation is that `Content-type` is not `multipart/form-data;` but it is `text/html; charset=utf-8`

So basically in your call you don't need to pass `Content-type` in headers

Python example:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {jwt_token}', 
    'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token
}
files = { 
    'formData': (
        dashboard_path, 
        open(dashboard_path, 'rb'), 
        'application/json'
    )
}

response = self.session.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

### EDIT 30.08.2021

I've noticed that for some reason when I was running Superset with `AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH` on production the solution above stopped working.

It requires additionally header `Referer` to be included in headers, so more safe option would be

```py
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json', 
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {jwt_token}', 
    'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token,
    'Referer': url
}
files = { 
    'formData': (
        dashboard_path, 
        open(dashboard_path, 'rb'), 
        'application/json'
    )
}

response = self.session.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use POST instead of GET ?

Comment: Hi, 2023 here. This does not seem to work anymore - if i'm doing it via bash scripts.

Comment: Hey @kabooya what version of Superset are you using?
I guess that if you're doing it through bash scripts, you're using curl. could you write the command that you're using?

Comment: ```curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d "$payload"   superset-dashboard:8088/api/v1/security/login``` to get the Bearer token. Then to get the CRSRF token: ```curl -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"   -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"   superset-dashboard:8088/api/v1/security/csrf_token/ ```
And finally to update assests ```curl -s -X POST http://superset-dashboard:8088/api/v1/assets/import/   -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"   -H "X-CSRFToken: $csrf_token"  -F "formData=@$FILE_PATH" ```

URLS are like this bc of Docker setup

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to provide a password for the database connection for the import to work. Here's the way to do that via Python code. [Source](https://api-docs.preset.io/#5589e9d4-95e5-42b9-9c33-0aa847d94a24)

```python
IMPORT_API_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1/dashboard/import/"

def get_superset_access_token():
    # Authenticate and get access token
    response = requests.post(
        "%s/api/v1/security/login" % SUPERSET_HOST,
        json={"username": SUPERSET_USERNAME, "password": SUPERSET_PASSWORD, "provider": "db", "refresh": True},
    )
    access_token = response.json()["access_token"]
    print("Received access token.")
    return access_token

# Function to import dashboard from a zip file
def import_dashboard(zip_file_path):
    with open(zip_file_path, 'rb') as file:
        files = {'formData': ('dashboard.zip', file, 'application/zip')}
        payload={'passwords': '{"databases/{{DatabaseYAMLFile}}": "{{DatabasePassword}}"}','overwrite': 'true'}
        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {get_superset_access_token()}", 'Accept': 'application/json'}
        response = requests.post(SUPERSET_HOST + IMPORT_API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, files=files, data=payload)

        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise Exception(f"Failed to import dashboard: {response.text}")
        print("Dashboard imported successfully!")
```

`overwrite` is an optional param. I had 2 yaml files in my zip in the databases folder, the import failed when I added both the files and passwords in the API call. It worked only when I specified just 1 file.