# Superset API: upload dashboard

Tags: apache-superset

I'm trying to upload a dashboard via the superset API, but seem to be stuck.

I'm using Superset in a Docker container on port 8080. Then, i made a python file with following code.

```py
session = requests.session()


# Perform a POST request and capture the response
login_payload = {
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "admin",
  "refresh": True,
  "provider": "db"
}

login_response = session.post(
  url='http://localhost:8080/api/v1/security/login',
  json=login_payload
).json()

# Extract the access token from the response
access_token = login_response["access_token"]
print("Access Token:", access_token)

# Extract the csrf token
csrf_response = session.get(
  url='http://localhost:8080/api/v1/security/csrf_token/',
  headers={'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
).json()

csrf_token = csrf_response["result"]
print("CSRF Token:", csrf_token)


# Make the import request
import_response = session.post(
  url='http://localhost:8080/api/v1/dashboard/import',
  headers={
      'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
      "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token,
      'accept': 'application/json', 
  }
)

session.close()

# Display the response
print("Response from Superset API:")
print(import_response.text[:4000])
```

I can succesfully get an CSRF token and an access token, but on the last post, i always get a "user confirmation needed" error. The response code is 200 though.

I have looked into this problem via the SO forum but the old solution, mentioned here [Import dashboard in superset through api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67984099/import-dashboard-in-superset-through-api), does not seem to work anymore